# BIP38 Encryption

Tags: blockchain.info, passphrase

Like many people, I created a paper wallet on BitAddress.org for the first time a month ago. I chose to use BIP38 encryption like an idiot. I'm not sure if I typed in my password wrong, but I have entered every password I can think of to no avail. First off, why would this website not have a "confirm password" section, and 2nd, how in the heck am I supposed to retrieve my first purchase ever from this paper wallet if the passcode I believe I used, is not working? A keystroke of bad luck, is what that was! Any ideas? Is there any place I can send this just using a private encrypted key? Thanks! Us noobs. Need to be looked out for.

Answer (score 2):

> how in the heck am I supposed to retrieve my first purchase ever from this paper wallet if the passcode I believe I used, is not working?

Sadly, if you created a BIP38 paper wallet and lost the password, then your bitcoins are locked away forever. A password protected wallet would be kinda useless if there was a way to circumvent the password protection. With financial sovereignty comes responsibility, hopefully you only have a small amount locked away in that wallet.

If it was just a matter of one wrong keystroke, you can maybe look up some sort of password brute-forcing software online. This might end up being a fair bit of work, but it may be possible to recover your funds this way.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If the password was not strong enough and has only few characters, you can try the below script to brute force:

https://github.com/neocogent/misc/blob/master/scripts/bip38scanx